# How would I change multiple filenames in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, rename

I am trying to remove parts of a name "- xx_xx" from the end of multiple files. I'm using this and it works well.

dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace " - xx_xx","" }

However, there are other parts like:

" - yy_yy"
" - zz_zz"

What can I do to remove all of these at once instead of running it again and again changing the part of the name I want removed?

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest way**

You can keep on stringing `-replace` statements until the cows come home, if you need to.

```
$myLongFileName = "Something xx_xx yy_yy zz_zz" -replace "xx_xx","" -replace "yy_yy"
```

*More Terse Syntax*

If every file has these, you can also make an array of pieces you want to replace, like this, just separating them with commas.

```
$stuffWeDontWantInOurFile =@("xx_xx", "yy_yy", "zz_zz")
$myLongFileName -replace $stuffWeDontWantInOurFile, ""
```

***Yet another way***

If your file elements are separated by spaces or dashes or something predictable, you can split the file name on that.

```
$myLongFileName = "Something xx_xx yy_yy zz_zz" 

PS> $myLongFileName.Split()
Something
xx_xx
yy_yy
zz_zz

PS> $myLongFileName.Split()[0] #select just the first piece
Something
```

For spaces, you use the `Spit()` method with no overload inside of it.

If it were dashes or another character, you'd provide it like so `Split("-")`.  Between these techniques, you should be able to do what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this stuff, and maybe I wasn't clear. It's not that there are multiple instances of this convention in the same filenames, it's spread out across different file names. For example: filename - xx_xx.html or filename2 - yy_yy.html or filename3 - zz_zz.html. ///// On review, the first answer nails it.

Comment: This is great. However, I found out that the naming convention is sometimes different and  is something like "-xx_xx-yy_zz-X-Y" or "-xx_xx-aa_bb-X-Y" and I want to remove all of that. When I use your first option and enter this in instead of " - xx_xx" it doesn't work. Why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

If as you say, the pattern  `- xx_xx` is always at the end of the file name, I'd suggest using something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '<TheFolderWhereTheFilesAre>' -File | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { 
        '{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '\s*-\s*.._..$'), $_.Extension 
    } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Remove the `-WhatIf` switch if you are satisfied with the results shown in the console</sup>

Result:

```
D:\Test\blah - xx_yy.txt      --> D:\Test\blah.txt
D:\Test\somefile - zy_xa.txt  --> D:\Test\somefile.txt
```

Regex details:

```
\s         Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
-          Match the character “-” literally
\s         Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
.          Match any single character that is not a line break character
.          Match any single character that is not a line break character
_          Match the character “_” literally
.          Match any single character that is not a line break character
.          Match any single character that is not a line break character
$          Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```